# Python redirect output after os._exit

Tags: python, multithreading, redirect, stream, exit

I have thread which is supposed to close whole application, so I use os._exit(1). But I also want to redirect output from my program to file and the output file is empty after all. Simple example:

```
import os

print('something')
os._exit(1)
```

Running program with:

```
python myprogram.py > output.txt
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is this what you say? You execute a python script from the shell with `> output.txt`? The script has one thread that executes `print('something')` and the `os._exit(1)` and that you do not find the text `something` in `output.txt`?

It should be there exect somebody redefined sys.stdout in your script or did something else.

To be sure you really executed the `print()` statement and that not some other code aborted your script, you can add following lines between the `print` and the `os._exit(1)`  `with open("test.txt", "w") as fout:` and `print("I was here", file=fout)`

Comment: Yes, I add these two lines and `"I was there" is written in test.txt`, but still output is empty. I even created new file with only this simple example in topic with no threads and output is empty.

Comment: hmmm. pls retry following:
try `print("I was here. sys.stdout=%s / %s" % (sys.stdout, sys.__stdout__), file=fout)`
and show what you get

Comment: if still empty try following line directly before `os._exit()`
`sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: It worked after adding `sys.stdout.flush()`, thank you.

Comment: yep. `os._exit()` is exiting rather brutally() There is a reason  it is prefixed with an `_`.

However I don't know any other way to  exit even if some other threads are hanging.
So I'm also using `os._exit()`

Comment: then you should probably also add `sys.stderr.flush()` perhaps lateron you will forget and you want to call. `python myprogram.py > output.txt 2> outputerr.txt` or `python myprogram.py > output.txt 2>&1`